# DocuSign: text fields get truncated when recipient signs envelope

Tags: docusignapi

I have an app that uses embedded signing to allow two types of users to sign forms.

I have a template with two recipients. All of the fields are assigned to Recipient 1 and are set as collaborative fields and changes require initials. The template has a signature tab for Recipient 1 and no signature tab for Recipient 2.

My bug is this:
Recipient 1 views and signs the envelope. Recipient 2 views the envelope and clicks 'submit' button. When Recipient 2 clicks 'submit', a text tab on the form simultaneously gets truncated after a comma in the text.

Here is an example of the envelope history from DocuSign: 
Entry 1:

```
3/25/2018 | 03:38:49 pm 

Recipient 2 (English (US))

Action: Viewed In-Session

Activity: Recipient 2 viewed the envelope in a session hosted by Form Signing Service [documents:(Form 1243.pdf)]

Status: Sent
```

Entry 2:

```
3/25/2018 | 03:38:57 pm 

Recipient 2 (English (US))

Action: Document Markup

Activity: employer|businessName tab in Document:[Form 123.pdf] on Page:[1] value changed from [Acme Manufacturing, Inc] to [Acme Manfacturing, ]<br />employer|addressFull tab in Document:[Form 123.pdf] on Page:[1] value changed from [1000 Main St Terrace Blvd, Albany, New York, 02108] to [1000 Main St Terrace Blvd, Albany, ]<br />

Status: Sent
```

Entry 3:

```
3/25/2018 | 03:38:57 pm 

Recipient 2 (English (US))

Action: Signed

Activity: Recipient 2 signed the envelope

Status: Sent
```

I have a customer who is seeing this issue on every envelope, however my team has not been able to reproduce it. Because it happens at the moment Recipient 2 signs, I wonder if something in the embedded view itself is cutting off the text.

Comment: Are your saying that Recipient2 is not changing from [Acme Manufacturing, Inc] to [Acme Manfacturing, ] and from [1000 Main St Terrace Blvd, Albany, New York, 02108] to [1000 Main St Terrace Blvd, Albany, ], is it DocuSign truncating these two fields?

Comment: @AmitKBist yes that is correct.